# Implementing Time-range Email Delivery in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm currently facing the challenge of setting up time-based email delivery in Journey Builder.

I want to restrict email delivery to a specific time slot, 9am to 10pm, but unfortunately, Journey Builder doesn't offer a built-in option for time slots. After searching, I found a potential solution and would appreciate guidance on how to implement it effectively.

The proposed solution involves updating a data extension with a timestamp and using a split decision to determine whether email should be sent or awaited based on that timestamp. However, I couldn't understand how to make the user who goes through the decision split able to receive the email again.
If anyone has implemented a similar approach or has alternative suggestions for achieving time-based email delivery in Journey Builder, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Additionally, if there are best practices or specific considerations when dealing with timestamps and wait activities in Journey Builder, please share them.

Thank you in advance for your help!